# Multi dimensional array from mysql for data visualization

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array, mysqli

First timer so please bear with me. Probably got this all wrong.

I am trying to return a multi dimensional array from the results of mysqli query.

```
$results= mysqli_query($con,"SELECT color, COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE type = 'post' AND author = '$user_ID'");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($results) {
```

I'd like to return something that ends up in this format.

```
$data = array(
  array(
    $row['color'],
    $row['COUNT(*)']
  ),
  array(
    $row['color'],
    $row['COUNT(*)']
  ),
  ....
  array(
    $row['color'],
    $row['COUNT(*)']
  );
);
```

This would then be used to populate a pie chart showing the color percentages. Any help would be appreciated.

When I create the arrays manually I get the desired results but I can not get any where trying dynamically.

```
$data = array(
  array(
    'red',
    20
  ),
  array(
    'blue',
    36
  ),
  ....
  array(
    green,
    10
  );
);
```

Comment: are you looking for `mysqli_fetch_assoc`? http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php . As an side, you should use an alias for `COUNT(*)`

Comment: Maybe? How would that play out?

Comment: I would recommend you spend some time familiarising yourself with aggregation functions in MySQL.  Look into "GROUP BY": https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: Went and played around with "GROUP BY" I can echo the results in a format close to the desired format but I am not sure how to get them into the desired array structure. echo ("" . $row['color'] . ", " . $row['COUNT(*)'] . "");

Comment: Can you update your code so we can see the progress you have made?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$rows_colors = array();

while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {

    $rows_colors[] = $r;
}

// Verify with:
print_r($rows_colors);
```

Comment: I gave this a try and it just prints 'Array()'

Comment: @Henry Did you run $results query before? If your query had any results its not possible that you are getting an empty array.

Comment: I've been able to get to a semi-working result that returns the results I am looking for using a mix of what's been responded here. For some reason I can not get the dynamic array to populate the visualization. If I create and array manually the results populate but not from the dynamic for some. Looks like one more hurdle to jump.